# login to website using PHP or another language and password_hash

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, web

I tried to log in with my username and my password on the site by doing it through my site, but I encounter the following difficulty, which obviously prevents me from using, for example, file_get_contents.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function hash_password( form ) {
    var login = form.elements['username'].value;
    var passwd_md5 = hex_md5(form.elements['password'].value);
    var passwd_hash = hex_md5(passwd_md5 + '66446' + login);

//  uc = navigator.appCodeName + ' ' + navigator.appVersion;
    // Set up redirect url
    var url = '/login.php?';
    var new_url = 'login.php';
//  new_url += '?goto=' + escape(url);
    new_url += '?login=' + escape(login);
    new_url += '&pass=' + escape(passwd_hash);
//  new_url += '&uc=' + escape(uc);
    // Submit the form
    window.location.href = new_url;

    // Ignore default submit
    return false;
}
// -->
</script>
```

The login form is this

```
<div class="LoginForm">
    <form onsubmit="return hash_password(this)" id="login" class="login">
        <div class="ttl">Вход</div>
        <label>
            <span>Потребител</span>
            <input type="text" name="username">
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Парола</span>
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Вход" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    </form>
    </div>
```

Uses the get method because toggle httpfox does not show a post method. If anyone can help with something I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Looks like you're staging a XSS.... not sure someone is going to help you.

Comment: Does the target site really accept the password in a GET request?